# Why use data star (data-*) attribute in html5?

Tags: javascript, html, html-dataset

I was going through HTML5 and I found data-* attribute is new to HTML5. But I didn't understand its importance. As per its [definition from w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) I understood:

> - The data-* attributes is used to store custom data private to the page or application.

**Question**: What does it mean by custom data? How we can use data-* to store custom data?

> - The data-* attributes gives us the ability to embed custom data attributes on all HTML elements.
>
> The stored (custom) data can then be used in the page's JavaScript to create a more engaging user experience (without any Ajax calls or server-side database queries).

**Question**: We already can add attributes to an element and use it in JavaScript, then why use data-* attribute?

Comment: Like for example, if you want to store an `id` to a `div`, you would put something like `data-someid="1"`, then get it using *(in JQuery)* `var someId = $("div").data('someid')`

Comment: So the benefit is i can put anything as an attribute name and use it in javaScript.

Comment: The question I linked is somewhat old, but I think it gives a good answer. Note that the DOM API alluded to by the top answer is [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset), which is indeed available in most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data-* for better and most flexible organization.
A practical example would be something like that:

```js
$("#result").text( $("#player").data("age") + " years old, " +
"Actual Team: "+$("#player").data("team") );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">

</script>
<!-- For Example, multiple data in a single div-->
<div data-age="33" data-team="Real Madrid" id="player">
       Cristiano Ronaldo profile: <span id="result"></span>
</div>
```